# Asks me to Login when I run from CD

Tags: login, live-cd

I just downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu 10.10 and burned it to CD. When I click Try Ubuntu, it starts up and then asks for Login info. I couldn't find anything on the website (though I didn't search very hard). Does anyone know what it is.

**Edit:** If I must ask the obvious question, then what is the username and password?

Comment: Yes, in some strange cases it may ask you for the login (which is a bug). But if it does, try user "ubuntu" and password "ubuntu", or user "ubuntu" and no password (note that both the login and password are case-sensitive).

Comment: i had that problem in earlier versions too and the info is what rafalcieslak said

Comment: @rafalcieslak: why do not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in some strange cases it may ask you for the login (which is a bug).

But if it does, try using:

**user**: ubuntu, **password**: ubuntu

or

**user**: ubuntu, **password**: (blank password)

(note that both the login and password are case-sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

The liveCD have only account Ubuntu

Comment: And it has no password and is set to automatically log in.

Answer (score 2):

I would try redownloading (or [checking the md5 sum](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/58950)) and burning the iso again.