# Is the Ubuntu direct download exactly the same as the torrent?

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, download-speed

Is the default download of `ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso` identical to the torrent `ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent`?

I'm asking because am finding the direct download 25% faster, but would be happy to seed back to people if I can simply place that file over my only slightly started torrent and then verify the data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, no matter where you download it (so long as it's an official source) the ISO will be the same.

You can check the hash to make sure the download is correct:

- [Where to find the checksums of Ubuntu ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9417/where-to-find-the-md5sums-of-ubuntu-iso-images)
- [How to verify that the ISO I downloaded is bootable before I burn it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31888/how-to-verify-that-the-iso-i-downloaded-is-bootable-before-i-burn-it)