# Difficulty trying to mount an ISO file "mount: you must specify the filesystem type"

Tags: command-line, mount, filesystem, iso

I have an .iso file which I would like to mount. I have made a folder in /mnt/iso as a mount point. Now I try:

```
sudo mount -o loop filename.iso /mnt/iso
```

and the reply is:

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

and the folder of /mnt/iso is empty. I have tried using

```
sudo mount -o loop -t ext4 filename.iso /mnt/iso
```

it says that mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error  (and more text)...

I found the filesystem type from using df -T and mount at the command line.

What could be missing or wrong?

Comment: have you done an md5sum of the ISO to check that it is a valid ISO?

Comment: @fossfreedom, no I haven't, good idea, but I have no idea how, can you give me a hint? (is it possible that the .iso is faulty?)

Comment: good Q&A here that should help... http://askubuntu.com/questions/31888/how-to-verify-that-the-iso-i-downloaded-is-bootable-before-i-burn-it

Comment: Did you read `man mount`? `df -T` and `mount` describe the _current_ state of the system. If you ran the commands _before_ you mounted a .iso, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filetype you need for mounting a .iso formatted file is **iso9660**. Here's an example:

A good .iso:

```
walt@wombat:~(0)$ file  /usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.iso  
/usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.iso: # ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data  MT410 ' (bootable)  `
```

A directory to mount it on:`

```
walt@wombat:~(0)$ ls -ld ~/tmp/mp  
drwxrwxr-x 2 walt walt 4096 2012-01-01 13:55 /home/walt/tmp/mp`
```

The actual mount:

```
walt@wombat:~(1)$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.iso /home/walt/tmp/mp    
mount: warning: /home/walt/tmp/mp seems to be mounted read-only.`
```

And here it is!

```
walt@wombat:~(0)$ ls !$  
ls /home/walt/tmp/mp  
boot  readme.txt  
walt@wombat:~(0)$  df -H /home/walt/tmp/mp  
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/loop0             1.9M   1.9M      0 100% /home/walt/tmp/mp  
walt@wombat:~(0)$
```

Comment: It may also be udf instead of iso9660.  Likely if the image is meant for a DVD.

Comment: That's why I used the `file` command, to be sure what the image was.