# Bootable USB and CD not detected

Tags: boot, usb

I created a bootable usb as well as a bootable cd to install ubuntu. Unfortunately, my medion PC (running windows 10) does not detect neither the usb nor the cd.
I am pretty sure that these bootable devices were properly created as I can start from them on hp computer.

I tried refind but the bootable usb and cd are not detected either.

I disabled the secure boot in the efi as described in several forums. It did not bring anything. I have not the option to use the legacy bios.

I tried other linux distributions I get the same: bootable devices are not detected. Only bootable windows installation usb or cd are detected.
Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Can you change your bios to only boot from cd?

Comment: 1st thing : are you triple sure that your usb or cd booted perfectly ? 2nd thing : are your iso file is ok means verified ? Is your iso file is boot-able or not ? if you can't then this will help you i guess link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31888/how-to-verify-that-the-iso-i-downloaded-is-bootable-before-i-burn-it

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the USB is bootable and the iso fine as everything opens fine on another PC as well as with MobaLiveCD.

Yes I can setup the PC to only boot from the usb (or from the cd drive).