# Problem installing Lubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, lubuntu, compaq

After I boot the Live-CD I can't select try Lubuntu or Install Lubuntu and I end up hanging on that screen.

My PC specs are:

- Compaq Presario s4214bd 2.4ghz Intel Celeron.
- Windows XP/Ubuntu 10.04 dual boot.
- 768mb Ram.
- Nvidia 6200 Graphics card (I've switched between the onboard and PCI(this one) still no luck).

I really want to use Lubuntu and I've been trying everything for the past 2-3 hours.

Anything will help.

Comment: please add to your question the "everything" you have tried.  That will help us to help you with answers you havent already tried.

Comment: As nitstorm said, it sounds like a corrupted image, my advice would be to download the iso again and burn the disc at the slowest burn rate, thus ensuring the quality of the iso is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a corrupted image. Try downloading the image again and burning it onto a disc at the slowest possible speed. Also [check the MD5 sum](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/58950) of the downloaded image against the image at the site. Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install `lubuntu-dekstop` on top of your current Ubuntu installation. 
just type in a terminal:

- `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

and then at your log-in screen select lubuntu instead of your current desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, you should make sure to check the installation medium (CD/DVD or USB flash drive) on boot-up. To do this, select `Check disc for defects` from the menu. (This applies to USB flash drives as well as CD and DVD media.)