# Where are the instructions for checking md5 checksums?

Tags: md5sum, checksums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)

Where do I find instructions for making sure the Ubuntu ISO I download is correct?