# Bootable USB stick created for installation doesn't work

Tags: live-usb, iso

I've downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 iso and followed the instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. After I tried the usb disk I got to the Ubuntu live menu, but after choosing run live ubuntu the systems freezes and restarts itself. I've tried this on a Lenovo T61p, an HP pavilion and an Acer Aspire One; all the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [unetbootin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unetbootin) to make a bootable usb. It's nice and simple

Or from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

also available for windows

Comment: OK, that worked! I downloaded unetbootin (from Windows) and followed the instructions. The the live usb worked like a charm. At least, on my Lenovo. Will try also on my other computers.

Comment: I tried this also on my Acer Aspire One and it gave me a kernel panic. And then nothing. So...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad image or bad USB stick or a combination of both:

You can check the integrity of the file you downloaded here:

- [Where are the instructions for checking md5 checksums?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157786/where-are-the-instructions-for-checking-md5-checksums)

And after you've made the USB stick use this page to test the installer before you proceed:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: I think it's the image. I've tried with the iso from 12.04 and it's working. But strangely, everytime I download the 12.10 iso this happens, so maybe something inside the iso isn't koosher.

Comment: I've checked the md5 checksum and the matched. Still, the usb is not working on my HP Pavilion laptop.