# After Wubi install Ubuntu 12.10 stuck up at boot screen

Tags: wubi

I have Windows7 Dell Inspiron laptop with following configuration

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
Intel Core i3 
4GB Ram

First I created a installtion DVD as per the steps and it got successfully burned from ISO image of 12.10 64bit. If I try to install Ubuntu or Selecte Try Ubuntu it is stuck up at boot screen with no specific error. Few forum suggested to change boot parameters but I couldn't understand appropriate option for me.

Secondly I created a USB drive from ISO image and used it but same results were optained.

Finally, I installed Ubuntu using the wubi installer. There weren't any errors during the install, and I can select Ubuntu from the boot menu. When I select Ubuntu, it is stuck up at boot screen and even waiting for a quite long few minutes 5-10 it never recovers and only option is to reboot.

I am not sure if this is incompatiblity between Ububtu 12.10 64bit with hardware that I have. Do I need to try long term support version? Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/205242/25656) in case there's a problem with your imaging.

Comment: Thank you, I've checked the md5 checksum and it matched. Still, none of the option USB/ DVD / WUBI works for 12.10 iso file. Also confirmed integrity via option described. Could it be because of this iso? will 12.04 give similar problem?

Comment: Did you go straight to installation? Did you try the "live" option first? Did that work?

Comment: I have not tried live option from the USB but I recall when I tried  Try Ubuntu from DVD there was same problem. Anyway I will try Live option with USB.

What is significance of live option over installation?