# How do I install a program using a .md5 file?

Tags: md5sum

This is a very basic question that probably has a very easy answer.
I am a frequent customer at humblebundle.com and some of the games
come in a format called ".md5". I understand it is a format that is used
to check an image for errors (after some very superficial googling).
Is it possible to open the file with a specific program or is it necessary
to use a terminal? Don't get me wrong, I am a fan of the terminal, but I am
a non-programming-languages-knowing kind of guy who just uses Ubuntu for the
fun of it. I would appreciate any answer.
Thank you in advance in case you are taking a look at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you found via Google, MD5 files are used to check the validity of a file when compared with the original.

As for installing via an MD5 file, that's impossible. MD5 files are *only* for testing validity.

My guess is that those games that come in, like you say, the .md5 format were one of two things:
1. The download got *really* messed up and you only got the .md5 file used for checking validity...
2. The file you downloaded only had the .md5 file in it, no game or other files.

To tell which one it is, try downloading the game again and then seeing if only the .md5 file is there. If it is, you know that that is the only file you can download and you should contact the site administrators/tech-support.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found out that I clicked the wrong link and now I'm figuring it how to use "sudo make", which will get the results I wish for, I'm sure!

Answer (score 5):

MD5 is an algorithm used, among other things, to check data integrity.

For example, read [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/157786/58950) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/58950) for instructions on how to check if a `.iso` file has been downloaded correctly (there's no need to rename the files, though).

So, you should get the programs, that mainly come as `.deb`, `.bin`, or `.tar.gz` (but other possibilities exist), besides of the `.md5` "checksum" file.

Comment: Well, between you and me I figure he got a pretty good answer, what? You give him the more in depth idea of _what_ an MD5 is and I give him his answer. We make a good team wot? :D