# How to proceed installation after reaching at 'Try Ubuntu'?

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

I can successfully boot from USB, the ubuntu purple screen comes. 2 options pop up: Try ubuntu & Install Ubuntu. After Clicking install ubuntu, in the next step memory space allocation is made, admin password is given. then "continue" is clicked. Ubuntu purple screen comes up, pc shuts down and reboots from USB again. Then the process repeats.. Pls help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Clarify me that weather you can reach try Ubuntu from inside windows 7 or at boot time ?

Comment: If you can get to the Ubuntu desktop from the "try", use the install icon from there.

Comment: Did you check the [integrity of the downloaded ISO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)? [These instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key) may help you too. Please edit your question if your issue is not related to any of the suggestions made on those links.

Answer (score 1):

Your install media is probably corrupt. When booting the install media there is an option to "Check CD for defects" this is somewhat misnamed. It really is a file-integrity checker, but the other way sounds better. Do that "Check CD for defects". Your files are probably @#$!.  Also give us more info: How much Memory do you have? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? et. al.