# When I use the Universal USB trouble

Tags: troubleshooting

When I use the universal usb installer, and it's extracting the files. I get about 200 errors. I have reinstalled ubuntu twice. It still gives me problems. I try using it anyways to boot to my flashdrive and I just get a screen saying missung default or ui configuration directive. I have tried every solution i have found on the internet, and nothing works. Even renaming the files. Please help, i would really like to start using ubuntu asap. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an alternative to Universal USB Installer. It is also provided through PendriveLinux and it's called YUMI. It works amazingly well and is really simple to use. It also has the advantage of being a "Multiboot" installer, meaning you can install multiple Bootable OSs and tools to a single USB drive. I haven't had any issues with it and I've been using it for nearly two years. The program is updated regularly to support the latest Distros and covers even some of the most niche bootable software.

Check it out here:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: well im trying to create a bootable flashdrive. and the program you provided is giving the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, seems you have a deeper problem. Can you describe exactly what errors you're seeing and what steps you take that lead to those errors?

Comment: well, in the extracting process I get the following.                     Elapsed time: 20 seconds/ remaining time: 0 /Files: 203  /Compression ratio: 100% /Errors: 200 / Total size:   752mb / Speed:23mb/s / Processed: 749mb /Compressed size: 749mb  and then in the results I get a bunch of data errors and its saying the file is broken.

Comment: @SethAudet Redownload the Linux ISO and check it's MD5/SH1 hash to make sure it wasn't corrupted during download(it's happened to me before), also try reformatting the USB drive. Drive errors can cause problems when setting up bootable drves. If you continue having issues try a different USB drive or even an SD card, just to make sure that the USB drive isn't bad(also has happened to me).

Comment: ok, so I reinstalled it, and now It starts to boot, and then it stops and says unable to find a medium containing a live file system. yes I looked at all the forums on here that had the problem. I tried pretty much all of them and no such luck.

Comment: @SethAudet Have you tried reformatting the USB drive like I suggested? I recommend not using Windows Format tool and instead follow the directions here:<http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/ >. Also have you tried using a different USB drive or SD card to see if those work. If they do, your USB drive is bad.

Comment: ok, the usb boots ubuntu perfectly on another computer I have, which is older then this laptop. So I know the usb is fine. I even booted from a virtual drive. Which booted up perfectly, and after a few minutes I get Unable to find a medium containing a live file system. @japzone

Comment: @SethAudet Okay now we're in the "process of elimination" phase. Have you tried it in a different USB port? For instance, on a Desktop PC if the front USB ports aren't working try the back ports. Also, have you had any other USB related issues on the PC? It could be a hardware problem, since the LiveUSB worked fine on another PC. Also a detailed description of what happens when you try to boot from USB would be useful. Use http://pastebin.com if you can't fit it in the comments.