# Unable to install any linux based os in my HP PAVILION DV6 notebook

Tags: installation, boot

processor:intel core i7 ram:8gb HD:1TB
I have windows 7 in my system.
I tried to install ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04 both with wubi and with dvd.With wubi even when the installation is successfull the os wont boot after some time.and with dvd it shows error "0x0009"and the intallation stops.

The same is the case with any linux based os i try to install.With fedora the installation stops after the display,"Detecting hard drive...".Are there any settings that must be changed in my system.

The Hard disk contains 4 partitions:

- C:,
- System,
- HP tools
- And recovery.

But C makes up almost 910 GB

---

**Update**

I deleted one partition and tried with both dvd and wubi..the process ends after displaying a message,"unexpected exit 0x0000"

if i try to boot from dvd the process stops and the system hangs before completion of the booting process

Please instruct me how to overcome this obstacle.I am stuck..!

Comment: No my friend mine is a NOTEBOOK not NETBOOK.

Comment: What are the specs?

Comment: processor:intel core i7 ram:8gb  HD:1TB

Comment: Oh well your specs clearly aren't the problem. I'm removing my previous comment from this thread.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what brand/model your notebook is?

Comment: Do you have Windows 8 or Windows 7? Do you have UEFI? Please add any further information in your question and not as a comment.

Comment: The Hard disk contains 4 partitions C:,System,HP tools And recovery.But C makes up almost 910 GB

Comment: @user68186 I dont know if my system has SSD or not..tell me how to find it.

Comment: Do you get this same error both in WUBI and when you boot from the DVD? In that case you may have a corrupted ISO file and corrupted DVD. See [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu cd?](See http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) for details on how to find if your DVD is corrupted.

Comment: @user68186 the same file and dvd worked with my friends..

Comment: Can you boot from the Ubuntu DVD and select "Try Ubuntu" and try it without errors? If so, open gparted while trying Ubuntu and see if gparted shows any errors for any of the partitions.

Comment: @user68186 No the process stalls in the middle

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which process stalls in the middle of what? Do you get the unity desktop? Can you use the system? Can you launch **gparted**? Does gparted stall? When does it stall, is it on a specific partition? Please edit your question with complete answer.

Comment: See the first item under: [My computer boots to a black screen. What options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). This is a long shot. But I have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four primary partitions may be the problem with your notebook.

**Background**

A hard drive can have only 4 primary partitions and not any more. To overcome this problem one of the 4 primary partitions can be removed and an extended partition can be put in it's place. The extended partition can have many logical partitions inside it.

See [the difference between primary and logical partitions](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/difference-between-primary-and-logical-partition/) for more details and determine if all the four partitions in your notebook are primary.

**Solution:**

If all are primary, then follow 
[My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu) and delete at least one partition.

**Warning:**

Deleting the wrong partition may make the system unbootable or you may lose your data files. It is best to make two sets of backups before making any changes to the partitions in any system.

Hope this helps

Comment: You have no idea how helpful you were.I was going gaga over this issue for the past week.But hey I am a novice.Anyway thanks dude..!

Comment: @NawinSS You are most welcome. Please accept the answer as "Accepted" by putting a green check mark on its left margin. This will help others with similar problems.

Comment: As I re-read your question, I am not sure this is the complete answer. **First:** WUBI should have worked as it does not need to create any partitions. It uses a big file as a virtual partition. That has its own problem, and I think you are better off without WUBI. **Second,** the DVD should not error out. It should only give you choices like "Erase everything and install Ubuntu." So your partitions may have some errors or some such thing.

Comment: I installed 12.04 using wubi and worked with it.It worked fine for some time but then it failed to boot,displaying an error"wubildr not found" and "prefix is missing".And regarding the error in partitions,I just restored my computer to factory settings a week ago and the partitions are the same as a new product..!

Comment: This is precisely why I don't like WUBI and now WUBI is not supported in 13.04 and above (WUBI does not work with the secure boot of Windows 8 either). WUBI breaks too easily and is only good for trying Ubuntu out for a short time. Thanks for the information on factory resett. Best of luck.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but unfortunately the solution didn't work for me...any alternates..?

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate which solution you tried and at which point it failed. Are you trying WUBI or a full install by deleting one of the 4 primary partitions?