# After installing Ubuntu via flash drive, only allowed to re-install Ubuntu or boot Windows

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 64-bit

After I successfully install Ubuntu using my flash drive and then reboot, my laptop forces me to choose my flash drive as the boot device. Otherwise it starts in Windows 7.

Also, when I choose the boot device, it starts the installation process again from the beginning.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5520.

Edit: I checked the disk management and there are 3 primary partitions and 1 "OEM partition".

Comment: See the answer to [Unable to install any linux based OS in my HP Pavilion dv6 notebook](http://askubuntu.com/questions/315075/unable-to-install-any-linux-based-os-in-my-hp-pavilion-dv6-notebook) and edit your question if you do not have 4 primary partitions.

Comment: Something is wrong either with your flash drive (corrupted installation files) or with the partitions of your hard drive. For some reason the installer is crashing when it tries to shrink the existing partition to make room for Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @karel This is an old question with an answer, I mostly agree that old obsolete questions waste time, (https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19630/flagging-old-questions-as-end-of-standard-support-or-end-of-life). However neither of the "duplicated" questions linked above have an accepted answer.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron It is accepted by the Stack Exchange network that having an accepted answer gives a question added importance. That's why the accept vote is worth 15 points instead of 10 points. Maybe the accept vote should be worth more than 15 points in certain cases, however complaining to me is not going to change much because this is a decision that was made by Stack Exchange and I'm just an ordinary Ask Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create Live usb correctly? check out 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
to install the iso correctly in your USB.

also follow the following link on how to install a dual boot of windows and ubuntu:
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/
(refer the tutorial from ubuntu's installation images)

Before directly plunging into your installation via the USB, i would first suggest you to boot from the USB in Live mode once, just to make sure that everything is intact and the download of the iso was perfect. Doing this would check the USB for errors(if any) and will either won't boot properly in live mode or will not boot at all. I suggest you run in Live mode first.

Regards,WinuxUser