# I don't understand why this is happening?

Tags: login, root, battery

I just installed Ubuntu, it boots and then I get stuck there :(

Problem shown link given below:

[Ubuntu Log In Problem](http://youtu.be/IwVvoKv5X0U)

Comment: Have you checked the hash/MD5 of the downloaded .iso file? I'd recommend to do that as first step. Here are some instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the Linux kernel, looks like it was not successfully installed, because of problems in the downloaded ISO. So I'd recommend you to download the Ubuntu ISO again and try to reinstall it.

As @user123492 mentioned, you should check the ISO integrity, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) will help you do that, click the first answer (the one marked as correct).