# Soft lockup when installing Ubuntu GNOME in virtual machine (Parallels OSX)

Tags: gnome, system-installation, virtualization, ubuntu-gnome

When installing Ubuntu GNOME 13.04 from an ISO in Parallels, I get the following error:

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!
```

This is shortly followed by another message:

```
INFO: rcu_sched self detected stall on CPU
```

[image: a screenshot of the installation screen displaying the errors]

Is this error the result of a problem with the Ubuntu disc image or something else? How can it be fixed?

Note I have checked the integrity of the disc image and checked the disks for defects. No problems were detected.

Comment: Have you [checked the integrity of the livecd](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)?  If that is fine you can also check the ISO by starting the process to boot into it then pressing `Esc` or one of `F1-F8` keys repeatedly (I usually use `F6`).  A menu will pop up and one to the selection will be "**Check Disk for Defects**"  These steps will tell you if the disk image is corrupt, if it is not, you can edit your question to include this info.  You will be more likely to get help then.....

Comment: Thanks, I had done that but no problems were found. Infact the menu with try the OS,install the OS etc. had the check disk for defects. I've put it in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the "Show Battery in Linux" as shown in this forum:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?71-Parallels-Desktop-7-Installation-(BUG-Soft-Lockup)&p=3642&viewfull=1#post3642

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this might answer this question. It is recommended to copy the essential parts of the solution into your answer. Please still keep the link as the source of the solution.