# Nothing Working Properly

Tags: 12.04

I just installed ubuntu and have been getting errors in everything. Music and Video Files are not running. Software centre cannot download a single software. What to do ?

Comment: i think you have not installed Ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: @Sushantp606, that will be difficult for him to do since his software centre doesn't work

Comment: `apt-get`, @thom ?

Comment: @wilf, Yes absolutely, but only if he is not terminalfobic like most GUI-users.

Comment: *Well it is better to use something that will work, to get the computer to work, @thom - checking hash files is harder anyway.* Vineet, you could get better answers if you were to expand on 'Nothing Working Properly'. Installing the `...extras` package would probably help though, for playing media files etc - What is the problem with the software centre?

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal by pression Ctrl+Aly+t to open termianl and then use the following command to install Ubuntu-restricted-extras

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Actually `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a software package for the computer operating system Ubuntu that allows the user to install essential software which is not already included due to legal or copyright reasons.

It is a meta-package that installs:

- Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
- Microsoft TrueType core fonts
- Flash plugin
- codecs for common audio and video files

after installing it you will be able to play audio’s and video as well.

Answer (score 0):

if "nothing" works "properly" then check the CD/DVD ( also the iso file ) for errors.
[How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)