# Software Centre Authentication Error 13.10

Tags: authentication

So I'm very new to Ubuntu, I don't know how to edit files, everything I do to improve Ubuntu is done through the Terminal using guides I find online. Basically since I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 overtop of my Windows 8, I've regretted it. Mainly because most of the things arnt working, gnome-terminal, software centre, etc.

Currently I've done all the things any guide online says to try and fix my Software Centre, I've viewed guides on askubuntu, wikihow, etc etc. None of them worked/work and now I'm getting tired of it. Everytime I try to remove/install a program in the Software Centre, I receive this Error:

```
Authentication Error

Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not    
available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name',     
{'name':':1.49'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

If you could please help me fix this, so that I could move on with Ubuntu, it'd be greatly appreciated. When explaining things to me, **please be very elaborate** - I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens if you try to install a package? Can you give us the whole secuence of commands that you entered and got back. Enter this command: `sudo apt-get install htop` in a terminal, and copy-paste the whole sequence in [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and give us the link in a comment.

Comment: `htop` is a light weight system monitor program, you can remove it when you are done I just want to know how it looks in your terminal. So we know exactly what's wrong here.

Comment: I'm unable to post anything given by the terminal, considering I can't open gnome-terminal or Xterm.

Comment: What happens when you try to open gnome terminal?

Answer (score 2):

It is probable that you have had an error in the installation procedure. What I would do in your case is *reinstall* Ubuntu.

You may need another PC to accomplish this steps:

- [Check the integrity](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/62483) of the Ubuntu-13.10 ISO.
- If it is OK, run the *LiveCD*
- Now resize/delete or format partitions in a way to let one for data and the other for Ubuntu. (see [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/62483))
- Install Ubuntu (yes, again) and now everything should work properly.

Comment: This is what I would have done in your situation, since it's the fastest solution from what we know right now.

Comment: You might also want to consider installing 12.04 instead of 13.10 as it has been around longer and therefore less likely to be buggy, moreover it's guaranteed to be supported for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is to type your password correctly onto the dialog box that appears just after you clicked Install/Remove. Debian package management system and the nature of Ubuntu requires the Administrative Rights for system-wide package installation. And the dialog you saw before this error(the password dialog you have cancelled most probably) asks for those rights.

Comment: I do not receive a dialogue box requesting a password upon installing/removing. I'm the Administrator.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you check if you have policykit installed issuing `dpkg --get-selections|grep polkit` and `dpkg --get-selections|grep policykit` from a terminal? They should return a few package names and the state `install` after a tab stop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'll try this.

Comment: I cant copy and paste anything from the ctrl + alt + f2 terminal, but everytime I entered the commands you listed above, it did say the name 'policykit/polkit' in red with the state install after a tab stop.

Comment: So PolicyKit is installed, right? Try `groups <yourusername>`. It should list groups `adm`(this is needed for PolicyKit) and `sudo` among a few more ones.