# Why I had redirected while downloading Ubuntu ISO?

Tags: release-management

Usually when I download a Ubuntu ISO from Ubuntu.com, I got it from *.Ubuntu.com path, a while ago; when I started the 14.04 Download, I got redirected to http://d3g7pb956c5s5x.cloudfront.net/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Is there any change in Ubuntu Back-ends? or this just temporarily for the Download spike on 14.04 release ?

Note : I use Getright as a download manager and it couldn't find any other Mirror having 14.04 new ISO (not even on Ubuntu.com! )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During releases Ubuntu.com uses a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to offload the load on the network of severs.

For most people it's transparent. As with all downloads make sure you check the MD5sum to ensure the download completed without errors:

- [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)