# Can't get Ubuntu to install ⠀

Tags: system-installation

Every time I try and download Linux, it just pulls up a CD burner program.
I’ve tried 3 different machines, and they all do the same thing.

After the 20 minute download, the Linux icon comes up on my desktop, I click it, and the CD burner program opens. So I tried burning it onto a DVD. After it burns I restart CPU, and boot from CD drive. It says it failed, so I restart normally, open up the CD, double-click the contents, and it just opens the CD burner program again. I've been trying this for almost a week now on 3 different machines, and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked the integrity of the downloaded files *and* CD/DVD states? Take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/17764/62483)

Comment: Sounds like you just wrote the iso file to the cd, instead of "burning image" which is a different operation.  Check options in the burner.

Comment: it says "image file"

Comment: @user278261 What operating system and CD burning programs are you attempting to use to burn the ISO to CD/DVD?

Comment: win xp dual core 3ghz, 2gb. was a windows vista buisness editon new. then previous owner put xp pro on it.
cd burner program is roxio. thats what pulls up when i try and open linux

Comment: Use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) to create the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

now a days, no need to burn dvd's, you just need to have a pendrive with capacity greater than size of image file. 2gb will be sufficient.

Be sure to backup all data.

Visit http://pendrivelinux.com/ and download UNIVERSAL USB Installer, select Ubuntu, select your pendrive letter(D:, E:, In your case it may be differen) very carefully.

wait an done.......

Now boot from USB. Normally F12 on Laptops. F9 on HP/COMPAQ Laptop.

F2/F8 for BIOS Setup on Desktops.

Change your Boot device priority in BIOS- (Boot) settings. Set boot from USB HDD/FDD as first boot device.

BIOS setup key may vary by model/Manufacturer. Carefully watch KEY OPTIONS when Motherboard/Manufacturer logo flash up.