# Serious error on first attempts to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Win7

Tags: dual-boot

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 from the website which I saved to my desktop with WinRar. My trial with winrar had expired so I have now tried it with Active@Isoburner but I'm getting no further. I eventually got it burnt onto a DVD(4.7gb) and tried to boot from DVD and normally. Neither way works.

It looks like its about to boot but then a message appears saying that `a serious error has occurred...the disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present...press I to ignore, s to skip or m for manual...`

At this point I'm lost and unsure what to do.
My laptop Toshiba Equium A210-17I is over 5 or 6 years old.
Available space on the Hard Drive is 24gb. 2gb RAM.
It originally came with Windows Vista Home Premium edition but about a year ago or more a friend wiped it clean for me as I was having no end of problems with Vista. He installed Windows 7 Ultimate(which I don't have a disc for).

**How can I resolve this issue and get Ubuntu to boot up?**
Do I have to install a previous version of Ubuntu first?
Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.
Kind regards.
Beetle.

Comment: How did you save it to your desktop using winrar? Did you download the `i386` or the `amd64` version?

Comment: Hi Theolodis, Thanks for the reply...I downloaded i386 version using winrar and then deleted it to re-download the i386 using Active@isoburner

Comment: Try the amd64 version, this could be the problem.

Comment: But it is highly probable that the burning didn't work as expected.

Comment: Have you checked the md5sum of your download? Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

If you need to, download the .iso from here from ubuntu http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and this time just leave the .iso as is and do not compress the file. (You have to right-click on the .iso to burn the Ubuntu installation disk).

If you copy and paste the .iso into the DVD folder and burn it, it will not work.

The following was taken from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

**Next** . . .

**How to burn a DVD using Windows7/8**

To install Ubuntu on a computer that currently runs Windows, you need to download the installation file and burn it onto the DVD, which you can then use to install Ubuntu. Once you’ve downloaded the file, **closely** follow the instructions below to burn your DVD.

[image]

[image]

When you are done, the burned DVD should contain a few files and should look something like this

[image: Ubuntu 14.10 contents]

If the contents of the burned DVD is the single .iso file like this, you did something wrong.

[image: FAIL]

**Next**

Insert the DVD in the DVD drive, save any unsaved work you may have on your computer, and power-off the device.

Turn the computer back on and make sure your BIOS settings are set to boot the DVD drive **First** on the list of boot devices.

On the Toshiba Satellite, **F12** is the button you need to press to enter the BIOS settings directly after turning on the computer (Your's may be different). Select save and exit and your computer should boot Ubuntu properly.

**Finally**

It is usually recommended you use a USB device to install Ubuntu rather than a DVD if your device is capable of selecting a USB drive as a boot device. The BIOS setting for a USB installation is the same as for the DVD; place the USB drive at the top of you list of boot devices to boot first.

You will need to download [Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.3.exe](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.3.exe)

[image]
[image]
[image]

More information can be found at the following:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

[http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

If you run into any errors, please post them.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. I will try these suggestions later and post my results.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. I will have a go at this tonight and I'll post my results. Can't wait to try Ubuntu as I'm sick of windows. Thanks.

Comment: glad to help, I know how it is

Comment: Well unfortunately I'm afraid I haven't gotten very far.

Comment: I got as far as trying to burn the file to disc using windows disc image burner but all I'm getting is an error code: 0x80004005. I've done a registry cleanup and tried it again but to no avail. Is windows/Microsoft designed to frustrate... If so - well done Microsoft.

Comment: Would it be something to do with the type of DVD I'm using?

Comment: IF it's a little scratched it might not work. If it's the registry for Windows Disk Image Burner, you can burn the disk using the command line. I'll post it as a new answer below.

Comment: Ok. I've looked up the error message 0x80004005 andI've done what was advised which was check system files by doing a system scan from the command prompt line also a hard drive disk check.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message from Windows Disk Image Burner. Should I try Lubuntu or Kubuntu or do it from a torrent? I am 3 days trying so far.

Comment: No, if the problem is Windows then installing a different flavor of Ubuntu shouldn't make a difference. Below is a way to use the "isoburn.exe" tool using the commandline.

Comment: isoburn.exe is not Windows Disk Image Burner so it might work

Comment: If you want to verify the integrity of the iso, you can check the md5 or the shasum to see if it matches. Here's a link: [http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)

Comment: if it does not match, you can download a fresh .iso or torrent file from the same page.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a quick and simple command-line way to burn a Live DVD using Command Prompt.**

First, open the Start menu and type command or cmd, click on Command Prompt.

Then, run the following command followed by a space, your DVD drive letter, colon, space, and the location (or path) of your iso file in quotations.

**`isoburn.exe /q`**

For expample, if my DVD drive is labeled as drive **"D:"** and the .iso file of ubuntu is saved to my desktop as **"ubuntu-14.04.iso"** I would run this command to burn the Live disk.

**`isoburn.exe /q D: "C:\Users\mchid\Desktop\ubuntu-14.04.iso"`**

BTW, you can drag and drop the iso into the command prompt to fill in the path for you if you don't feel like typing the location of the file.

Comment: source: [http://www.7tutorials.com/burning-iso-or-img-disk-images-windows-7](http://www.7tutorials.com/burning-iso-or-img-disk-images-windows-7)

Comment: I've gone through the command prompt method and it said at the end that the image was successfully burned to the disk but on reloading the disk it shows up as a blank disk. I have booted up from DVD via F12 option and have pressed "S" to skip mount and now I'm looking at a black screen with text in top left corner "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Ubuntu tty1"  "Ubuntu login"

Comment: You should not see a login on tty1 using a live disk. Either your are using the wrong .iso to install Ubuntu or something is wrong with Windows.

Comment: To check the firmware of your DVD drive, use "Device Manager" in Windows to uninstall the drivers by right clicking on the device. The drivers should re-install after you reboot as soon as windows recognizes the device. [http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-disc-image-burner-error-code-0x80004005/5351c08d-4f1a-4250-8321-f8dd31f49b63](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-disc-image-burner-error-code-0x80004005/5351c08d-4f1a-4250-8321-f8dd31f49b63)