# Fail to connect to socket, /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

Tags: system-installation, dbus, usb-installation

When I want to boot from CD, or install new version ( 13.10, 14.04) of Ubuntu, and also (elemntaryos) I got nothing in the monitor, recently I found it has the following problem

Fail to connect to socket, /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

I have surfed the Net., but all solution were for installed version of ubuntu, but I don't have it installed.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you check the integrity of the CD? see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd