# I got a "Failed to copy files... Possibly an old hard hard drive..." error during installation and now it says my hard drive is full

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I have built a simple computer to try Ubuntu out.
I tried to install Ubuntu through a USB flash drive. During the installation I got an error saying:

> "Failed to copy files... Possibly an old hard hard drive..."

After restarting my computer the installer says I don't have enough space on my hard drive and I am not able to format it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a clean disk right? Just boot a live session and reformat it. I would also re-download the .ISO file and [run a md5 check on it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd/392378#392378) to make sure it is clean. Then re-burn it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a step forward maybe:

I hope that USB flash drive is a "Live CD", if it is, boot it in 'Try it out'-mode and then  open a bash/Terminal with e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

In there, at the `$` prompt, type

```
lsblk
```

The response should look similar to this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 200,5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
...
sdg      8:96   1   1,9G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

*edit: added sdg and sr0 above*
*sdg is how an not yet partitioned device looks. It may have a partition *table* though.*
*sr0 is a CD/DVD R/W device*
With partitions added to the 1.9GB microSD card, in card reader:

```
sdg      8:96   1   1,9G  0 disk 
├─sdg1   8:97   1   1,8G  0 part 
└─sdg2   8:98   1    99M  0 part
```

---

From comment below:
It looks as if you have an `1.9G` disk - you need in the range of 6-10G when the install of 14.04 LTS is **finished** - judging from the content of **my** `/`.

You need to use 'gparted' to remove what there is now - while you're at it you will see what gparted says about the disk.

*one more edit*

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg bs=512 count=1
```

would wipe ALL partition data from the 1.9GB microSD card above. **IMPORTAN NOTE** If you attempt this - be VERY SURE THAT YOU TYPE WHAT YOU SHOULD - it will wipe the disk you **type the name of** - which might be something else than the one you intended.

In the end, if it differs from what actually is, and you cannot tweak it to be correct - then the disk is suspect and might be faulty.

...
*If you can make it work that way, you might try defining the partitions yourself:
Make /swap (4-8G? Depending on your RAM) and /boot (1-2G), the rest for /*

- *what is above is my setup on a "256G" SSD-disk.*
  *I have a separate disk mounted at /home for all my data, but that isn't necessary for a 'low data space' installation.*

Comment: This is the Response I got:
>NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:16    1 1.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:17    1   1.9G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0     1   7M    0 rom
loop0    7:0     1   922M  1 part /loop"
The hard drive's size is 40 gigs.

Comment: See addition above.

Comment: Like I said before the drive's size is 40G. The usb is 1.9G . I guess that means it doesn't recognize the drive. I have another one so I'll try it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes of course, the USB-thumbdrive has to be visible, forgot that `:-]

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by using a Windows 8 flash drive to format the hard drive. However, now I get a "Errno 30" message. Thank you for all the help @Hannu.

Comment: Strange errors... Might be caused by driver software issues. Maybe check whether it is possible to update the BIOS? If there is a newer one available.