# Error Desktop Manager not Active (Sometimes)

Tags: 14.04, hardware, lxde

Once again I have a weird bug. It doesn't happen every time I start my Ubuntu partition, but rather every once in awhile, maybe every third or fourth start?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with LXDE desktop. Sometimes however I get this error: after I log in I don't get any background, no desktop shortcuts, and sometimes my menu is missing some items.

I have seen the common errors where you uninstall `pcmanfm`, but I do not have that installed. I also checked for the file `~/.config/variety/scripts/set_wallpaper`, but I do not even have the `~.config/variety` folder. Any ideas? If you need more info let me know what you need.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell us what error you get? Anything of interest in the logs?

Comment: I am still a little new to linux, where would I find these?

Comment: open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T then `cd /var/log` `ls` will show you the contents.  syslog may prove interesting.

Comment: syslog.1 had the error in it from earlier when it didn't load right. Here is the log http://paste.ubuntu.com/8397301/, well most of it.

Comment: The part that jumps out at me is the error remounting read only. I would fsck the file system and verify SMART status on the drive. You may have a corrupt filesystem. The drive could also be failing. If none of that provides results you may also wish to test your RAM.

Comment: Tried all that, and no problem. My hard disk shouldn't be failing because I just bought this SSD new around 2 mounths ago.

Comment: Please edit and add the exact steps you "tried all that" with to your question and the "no problem" output results.

Comment: I ran fsck from a boot disk on /dev/sda1, and it came back clean. Then to test for smart status I ran, smartctl, and it says enabled. I tested ram with the memtest option in grub, and it didnt get any errors.

Comment: I think it may  have been that I had some nvidia drivers installed while I am running intel graphics. I have no idea why these where installed. But there some lines in the log complaining about nvidia. So we will find out.

Comment: Based on this line in your log `Sep 21 11:01:25 djfrost kernel: [    6.622147] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` please add the output of `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda`

Comment: You may also wish to review http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04/528077#528077

Comment: Sorry I have been unresponsive, I just recovered from a crash. Apppears to have been an update, however it is fixed now. I will get you the result of the smartctl test tonight, but it might be different now because I have lots of things in autoremove that shouldnt be there, and certain programs are missing icons and various things.

Comment: Did you check the integrity of the installation ISO before you installed? http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd

Comment: No I did not, and the sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda is no longer giving me output it says that test is starting and will finish in two minute, but will never give me output even if it finishes.

Comment: check the md5sum of your installation ISO. (see the link in my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have either a corrupt installation due to a corrupted ISO download or your drive is failing. If the checksums match, it's the latter and you need to replace the drive. If the former you should download the installation media again, verify the checksum and if it matches, reinstall.