# How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 20.04?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

How can I check the SMART status of a drive under 14.04 and beyond? I've seen [Checking HD SMART status on a fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147709/checking-hd-smart-status-on-a-fresh-install) but it doesn't seem to apply under 14.04 and later.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## [Disks Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks)

Launch the Disks Utility (If you don't have it already, you can install Disks via the Software Center or open a terminal and issue the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`.

[image: smart1]

Select the drive of interest then click on the menu button at the upper right corner and choose **SMART Data & self tests**

[image]

Note that sometime between 18.10 and 20.04 the menu option has moved from the "hamburger menu" to the 3 vertical dots menu as shown below.

[image: changes]

### [Types of self-tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Self-tests)

[image: screenshot]

- **Short:** Checks the electrical and mechanical performance as well as the read performance of the disk. Electrical tests might include a test of buffer RAM, a read/write circuitry test, or a test of the read/write head elements. Mechanical test includes seeking and servo on data tracks. Scans small parts of the drive's surface (area is vendor-specific and there is a time limit on the test). Checks the list of pending sectors that may have read errors, and it usually takes under two minutes.
- **Long/extended:** A longer and more thorough version of the short self-test, scanning the entire disk surface with no time limit. This test usually takes several hours, depending on the read/write speed of the drive and its size.
- **Conveyance:** Intended as a quick test to identify damage incurred during transporting of the device from the drive manufacturer to the computer manufacturer. Only available on ATA drives, and it usually takes several minutes.

### [How to interpret SMART-Attributes](https://superuser.com/questions/429639/howto-interpret-smart-attributes)

The most important attribute in terms of failure rates is likely the **196 - Reallocated Sector Count**, but considering [Google research paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf): _"...failure prediction models based on SMART parameters alone are likely to be severely limited in their prediction accuracy, given that a large fraction of our failed drives have shown no SMART error signals whatsoever." However, the majority of the drives (over 60%) in the study that failed did exhibit a smart failure, so as imperfect as it may be, it's still valid indicator.

Note that while the vast majority of recent drives support SMART not all drives do and implementations can vary. For more details on SMART see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: I am using `gnome-disk-utility 3.18.3.1
UDisks 2.1.7 (built against 2.1.6)` and the SMART option doesn't appear anymore. (?!)

Comment: @ElderGeek, I don't know. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place. I have `gnome-disk-utility 3.28.1
UDisks 2.7.6 (built against 2.7.6)` now and I see the option.

Comment: @MatthiasWeiler you wrote "In wily (15.10) it is not a gear anymore but the usual "menu" button"    <--  are you sure. Looks like the gear   is still a gear, definitely still there, and  the menu button is still a menu button still there     And   The difference is  that now you click the menu button and before you  would click the gear.   I have no idea what you mean by "it". The option has moved from the gear button to the menu button.  But there's nothing that was a gear and now is not a gear. No button has changed from one button to another button. Both buttons are still there.

Comment: @barlop I edited my answer and apologize for any confusion you may have experienced. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 104):

The commandline version of the `libatasmart` library used by Gnome Disks is called `skdump` part of the [`libatasmart-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libatasmart-bin) package which is not installed by default. Install by using:

```
sudo apt install libatasmart-bin
```

Next run the following command to see the SMART information by running the following command in the terminal (replacing `/dev/sda` by the path to your drive):

```
sudo skdump /dev/sda
```

As an alternative the `smartctl` from the [`smartmontools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=smartmontools) package could be used. Install by using:

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

You will then be able to get information on SMART by running the following command in the terminal (replacing `/dev/sda` by the path to your drive):

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

Note that `smartctl` tends to be overly verbose. Use the `-q errorsonly` argument to display only errors:

```
sudo smartctl --quietmode=errorsonly --all /dev/sda
```

Comment: If you don't want to install an MTA (Postfix) when installing `smartmontools`, use the command `sudo apt-get install smartmontools --no-install-recommends` - Postfix is the only package that won't be installed.

Comment: Also note that you may want to run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda > sda-smart.txt` since it can be a minor PITA to read the data from terminal.

Comment: A good walkthrough and tips can be found on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Can this also do a surface scan? I have a hard drive that passes SMART but fails a surface scan. I want to perform a surface scan on my laptop too.

Comment: @Chloe: please ask a separate question for the surface scan.

Answer (score 27):

### Ubuntu 16.04

This answer is migrated from a duplicate question closed here ([What happend to SMART data (disk selftest option)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865628/what-happend-to-smart-data-disk-selftest-option/865633?noredirect=1#comment1344034_865633)).

The question above has been changed to require Ubuntu versions after 14.04 but the answers haven't changed and don't apply to Ubuntu 16.04. As such it caused confusion as described in the closed question.

Select `Dash` the first option on the `Launcher` and type `disks`. Select the icon that appears. If the `disks` program isn't available you need to install it first with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

The `disks` main screen looks like this:

[image: disks main]

Notice the "hamburger" menu in the top right corner. Select it to get a drop down menu where you can select the SMART screen shown below:

[image: disks SMART]

If you require further explanation please comment below.

---

### SMART option greyed out

In comments it was mentioned the SMART option was greyed out. This can happen with NVMe SSD's. In this case referring to this answer:

- [How do I check system health?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038701/how-do-i-check-system-health/1038711#1038711)

You need to first install NVMe SSD specific SMART tools:

```
sudo apt install nvme-cli
```

Then run the program to report health of drive:

```
$ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 40 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 28,167,888
data_units_written                  : 19,397,424
host_read_commands                  : 561,183,142
host_write_commands                 : 171,788,833
controller_busy_time                : 1,354
power_cycles                        : 2,385
power_on_hours                      : 1,363
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 133
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 608
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 40 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 51 C
```

The most important data point is:

```
percentage_used                     : 0%
```

When it hits 100% it is time worry about replacing your drive. That said this drive is two years old and still at `0%`

Comment: Everything in the other answers still holds true (more or less) to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For me in 17.04 the Smart test option is grayed out?

Comment: I have several USB HDD drives where the SMART test option is indeed grayed out. It depends on the model.

Comment: The SMART test was greyed out for me in Ubuntu 20.04 and this solution still worked.