# How to install Kubuntu from working OS?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, usb, kubuntu

I have dual-boot system. Now, I want to erase all packages and all home's files on my **Kubuntu**, i.e I need **100% clean system**. I decided to make a bootable usb-stick. I tried to boot from it, got GRUB-menu with 3 options (1.Start Kubuntu 2.bla-bla(for manufactures) 3.Check for defects). I choosed first one. Then I'm getting kubuntu logo hanging for infinite time. I've done this before, why I can't do this now? BTW, all 2 **OS**es (Kubuntu and Windows) are working, so I can use them.

And I wanna ask - is there an option to do it with installer from desktop or whatever, but without booting from usb? If not, how I can fix problem booting from usb?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted USB write -- try re-downloading the ISO image, MD5 checking it, and rewriting it to the USB with Unetbootin (from Windows) or dd (from Ubuntu).

Comment: This should help put you on the right track: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd

Comment: @ZeissIkon I checked md5sum and it's different! I tried to redownload iso 5 times via different ways (mirror, torrent etc., but not via browser as default bc it's very and very slowly it can take hours).

Comment: @pushandpop Do make sure you're using the MD5 for the same ISO you're trying to install -- if the file is different, the MD5 will never match.  Otherwise, it sounds as if you have a bad Internet connection; can you download the ISO from another computer with a faster/better connection?  Local public library, for instance?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I have good internet connection (20 mbps). And it works just fine via torrents and mirrors. I was talking about default download way..

Comment: @pushandpop If you're consistently getting bad MD5, either you're downloading from a source with a corrupted file, or the transfer is getting damaged on the way to you.  The latter could come from a bad connection -- however, I didn't catch that it was only slow from Canonical.  I'd suggest starting the download just before you go to bed; it'll be done when you get up (or just let it run in the background while you do other things).

Comment: @ZeissIkon ok, i'm gonna try 14.04 instead of 14.10

Comment: @ZeissIkon I've just done! Still different md5, should i try to burn usb?

Comment: @pushandpop Are you *certain* you're comparing your MD5sum with the correct value from the file source?  I can't picture that many downloads getting corrupted without at least one being good...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm sorry, i was checking **sha256sum** - my bad. Now, I've checked it correctly and sums are equals, but still have infinite kubuntu logo (it's shining but nothing is happening even after 40min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me I've run into that problem with a bad USB write from a good file -- unetbootin sometimes changes an ISO in a way that prevents it from booting successfully; dd makes a faithful copy that, in my experience, always works.  It's also possible for a damaged partition to cause this kind of failure; recreating the partition table on the flash drive usually corrects that problem. If the MD5 is good, those are the two things to look for.

Comment: I tried different USB writers. Wubi? Yes, it's working, but AFAIK this one is not complete LInux, is it? I want complete OS.

Comment: Been a long time since I've used Wubi -- it installs the Linux in a virtualizer inside Windows, doesn't it?  Not quite what you're after, I suppose.  Last time I had trouble with unetbootin, I found using dd to copy the ISO to the USB solved the problem -- but you'll need to be in Linux to do that.

Comment: I'm gonna try another (3rd) USB and different distro. I'll put result today, I hope so.

Comment: Thats it! 3rd USB fixed this problem...

Comment: You probably need to recreate the partition tables on the two that didn't work; a very minor partition problem can cause the writes to get damaged in a way that won't fully boot.  Meantime, glad to hear it's working.

Comment: Thanks! You can edit your answer, so I can mark it as "solution" if you want.