# Wrong language when trying out 14.04

Tags: language-support, locale

I'm trying out 14.04 using a USB drive.  The first time I did this everything came up in German (which I was able to negotiate with some difficulty).  The second time everything came up in Spanish, which I hardly know  at all.  I tried `setlocale`, but I get `no se encontró la orden`, which I guess means "command not found."  (For some reason `sudo setlocale` returns the same message -- but in English!)   Here is what's in `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```

So how do I change that first line -- can I just *edit* the file `/etc/default/locale`?

Comment: Are you not prompted to chose your language after boot in the menu with the options "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu"? There should be a long list on the left afaik...

Comment: No, @ByteCommander, I just get a blank screen.  When I move the cursor to the icons on the left their names appear (currently) in Spanish: "Instalar Ubunti 14.04.1 LTS," "Archivos," etc.

Comment: huh? Strange! Screenshot? Did you validate the hash number of the Ubuntu image you downloaded and where did you get it from?

Comment: No, I didn't validate anything.  I got it from Releases.Ubuntu.com.  Rather than starting all over again, I'd much prefer just fixing this problem so I can do a proper installation (and understand what the process tells me...).

Comment: You have a live system at the moment, right? So the only thing you would have to do is to manually compare the hashes of the iso-file you downloaded with the one you can read at the Ubuntu download page. If your installation image has errors, you will only make it worse and get more errors and unexpected behavior the more you use it!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what "hashes" means, or how to find them for the iso-file I downloaded.

Comment: Look at this Q&A and come back when you verified your downloaded Ubuntu image (or got a new one that is verified): http://askubuntu.com/q/17764/367990

Comment: I just received the message: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"  I'd be happy to do that, if someone can tell me how.

Comment: I don't get that message. If there is a link you can click, do it. Else just ignore it. It does not matter really...

Comment: OK.  I looked up the three hashes shown for my version of 14.04.1 in the releases page.  I was unable to use the instructions on the page you referenced (md5sum didn't work), but I found all three in the file /cdrom/casper-rw.  (Just to check, I changed one digit and no longer found the string.)  So I don't think there was any error when I downloaded the ISO.

Comment: I'm clicking on "automatically move this discussion to chat."

Comment: But I got a message: since my "reputation is 4, not enough to chat."  So I guess I stay here...

Comment: So @ByteCommander, can I just *edit* the file /etc/default/locale?

Comment: Well, I found an answer to a related question advising the questioner to do just that, so I went ahead and did it.  But the language hasn't changed, presumably because I haven't rebooted.  I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1):

All that was necessary to fix the language problem: editing `/etc/default/locale` and correcting the first line to read

```
 LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

like the other lines. After a reboot everything was fine.

As muru stated: I didn't need to generate new locales as `en_US.UTF-8` was already used on my system

Comment: And running `locale-gen` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` as needed.

Comment: No, I hadn't done that, but I'm always ready to take advice, so I ran locale-gen just now.  (I'm not sure what it does, except give me a long list of languages...)

Comment: if you're adding a new locale, then you'll need it. Since you were already using the locale for some settings, probably nothing needed to be generated.