# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS won't install from live USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I have an Acer Aspire 5349 laptop and have been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I used linux live usb creator and mounted the .iso to the pendrive and I set my laptop to boot first from the usb and the computer recognizes it as usb Sandisk Cruzer micro so I dont know what the problem is. When I boot from usb it shows
"SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 4.06-pre7 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al" and nothing happens when I hit any keys. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try formatting your flash drive to FAT32 and try all the process again.

Comment: Use [win32diskimager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to write the iso to your usb drive.

Comment: It is in FAT32 and I used win32diskmanager and linux live usb creator

Comment: I dont now what the problem is.

Comment: ISO is for live CDs, AFAIK

Comment: I dont have a working cd drive, thats why you mount it to USB @It'sWillem

Comment: @BudRbanas Oh. k

Answer (score 0):

The Syslinux message tells us the USB creator has actually done its work on the USB, so it certainly looks like you have followed the process correctly.

This makes me think you may have a bad ISO image. Perhaps you should download it again.

Comment: I'm going to re-download it and mount it again and see what happens.

Comment: Downloading again wouldn't guarantee a "good ISO". Why not check the downloaded ISO instead? http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd

Comment: How do I "check" the .ISO? @mikewhatever

Comment: Well, you click the link I've posted for your convenience, and read on. ...here it is again, in case you can't find it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd