# WARNING: PAE disabled. Use parmeter 'forcepae' to enable at your own risk!

Tags: dell

I was about to load Ubuntu from a USB on a Dell D600 when I got the message:

> ```
> WARNING: PAE disabled. 
> Use parameter 'forcepae' to enable at your own risk! 
> This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU. 
> Unable to boot - please use kernel appropriate for your CPU.
> ```

Is it okay to enable PAE? I don’t want to break the computer so thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 6):

1. [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Burn it to a DVD
3. Boot the DVD
4. When you see the following screen:

   [image: Ubuntu Boot screen]

   **press any key** and you will see this screen:

   [image: Ubuntu Boot - Advanced Options]
5. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>

   *Note:* The boot command line is now available for editing and will remain so as long as no pop-up menu is visible.
6. Leave a space following the "--" and add `forcepae`.
7. The command will be executed when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed and the "Try Ubuntu" boot sequence will begin.

***All the above is completely harmless and will not damage your PC!***

---

If it works:

1. Choose "Install Ubuntu"

if it doesn't:

2. Your PC is too old now to support Ubuntu.  Get a new one...  **:-(**

Comment: Sorry it didnt work says the same thing "pae dissabled" how do inable it?

Comment: Ok....."WARNING: PAE disabled. Use parmeter 'forcepae' to enable at your own risk! This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU. Unable to boot - please use kernel appropriate for your CPU." Thats it... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh ok will do :)

Comment: Done!!! Hope it can help

Comment: I did it but it says: unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

Comment: @Natim Pas de chance **;-)** Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)