# Boot new 16.04 in Secure Boot Mode

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a Dell laptop with factory installed Ubuntu 14.04. This OS would boot fine with Secure Boot turned on. 
I have now installed 16.04 alongside 14.04, and I can dual boot.
I downloaded the 16.04 ISO from the Ubuntu site, but so far as I know it is not signed by Ubuntu. What do I need to do to make the 16.04 boot with Secure Boot turned on?

pgmer6809

Comment: Did you test it? I have installed 16.04 and I see /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic.efi.signed which... looks pretty signed to me.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried, and was able to boot the Ubuntu desktop 16.04 AMD64 image, written to a USB flash drive, with Secure Boot active on an HP EliteDesk computer. Thus, I can say with some certainty that this image *is* properly signed for Secure Boot. Several possible causes of your problem spring to mind, some of which you could correct but others you could not:

- **Image CPU type** -- Check that you're using the correct image file, and in particular, that it's for the correct CPU type, which should be AMD64 for the vast majority of computers. (AFAIK, i386 images *never* supported Secure Boot "out of the box.")
- **Image damage** -- Use the `md5sum` utility to verify the integrity of your download. (See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) for more on how to do this.)
- **Improper image preparation** -- Some tools, such as YUMI/Pen Drive Linux, create USB flash drives that can be booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode but not in EFI/UEFI mode. If you used such a tool, your disk might not be bootable in EFI mode. This isn't a Secure Boot issue per se, but you might be mistaking it for one. Try using Rufus, UNetbootin, or `dd` instead. In fact, even if you used one of these tools, switching to another one might be necessary, since there can be system-to-system quirks and incompatibilities.
- **Computer boot manager issues** -- You might be unable to access your computer's built-in boot manager, or you might be selecting the wrong option in the boot manager. For instance, many EFIs present two options for removable media, one of which boots in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and the other of which boots in EFI/UEFI mode. If you select the former, the disk might not boot if Secure Boot is active; you must select the option that includes the string "UEFI."
- **Non-Secure-Boot regression** -- You could be seeing a problem that's unrelated to Secure Boot, such as a new kernel bug. [Filing a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) would be in order in this case, but you'll need to track down the problem with more precision first.
- **New Shim or GRUB bug** -- Finally, you might have encountered a new bug with the Shim or GRUB package. If you're convinced this is what happened, you should [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) You might be able to work around it temporarily by swapping out the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file from the 16.04 image with the same file from the 14.04 image; however, before you do this, you should back up your working `/boot/efi/` directory tree from your 14.04 installation, since the installation is likely to replace your working `shimx64.efi` binary with a non-working one. (`bootx64.efi` and `shimx64.efi` are the same file; they're just named differently on the installation image vs. an installation to disk.)

It would also be helpful if you describe in more detail what you're doing and what's not working. You claim that the image is not signed, and I'm working under the *assumption* that this is because you've tried to boot it and can't get it to boot, but even with that assumption, there are details that could be important, such as any error messages you might be seeing. If there's any evidence that GRUB has launched, then that would tend to support a post-GRUB problem. Thus, describing *exactly* what's happening is important to better diagnose the problem. (If necessary, take a video, post it to YouTube, and post a link to it here.)

Comment: Hi Rod,  In fact I gave up too soon. When I switch to secure boot mode, and boot, I get a red box on the screen that says, "Invalid Signature Detected" with an OK box there. If I do a CR I get to the grub menu, which looks the same as when I do not secure boot. The grub menu will in fact let me boot 16.04, as well as 14.04.  Doing a Restart from the desktop is essentially the same. So other than the extra manual intervention step, there is no issue.

Comment: There is a 'signed' vmlinuz vers 4.4 in the /boot directory, but none in the /boot/efi partition. So I dont know why secure boot is complaining.

Comment: PS. I don't know if this matters, but when I did the install of 16.04, I had secure boot turned off, so that I could boot from the ISO usb Stick.

Comment: First, type `sudo efibootmgr -v` and verify that the first entry to be booted (as specified on the `BootOrder` line) references `shimx64.efi` rather than `grubx64.efi`. If the system boots via Shim, you should *not* see a scary warning like what you describe. If you're seeing such a warning when booting via Shim, chances are that indicates a firmware bug. In this case, I recommend you check with the manufacturer to upgrade the firmware. (They probably call it a "BIOS update," although it's really an EFI, not a BIOS.)

Comment: Hi Rod,I am trying to send you the output of gdisk, /boot/efibootmgr, and ls /boot/efi but this forum keeps telling me my comment is too long.

Comment: here is the output of efibootmgr=====sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001
Boot0001* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,c0f1f78e-84a4-4939-a314-ad0604093a86,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Grub2 HD(1,GPT,c0f1f78e-84a4-4939-a314-ad0604093a86,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)

Comment: here is the output of /boot/efi/ubuntu====sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001
Boot0001* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,c0f1f78e-84a4-4939-a314-ad0604093a86,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Grub2 HD(1,GPT,c0f1f78e-84a4-4939-a314-ad0604093a86,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
....

Comment: and here is the abbreviated  output of gdisk====sudo gdisk /dev/sda====Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2         1026048         1107967   40.0 MiB    FFFF  Basic data partition
   3         1107968         7399423   3.0 GiB     0700  Basic data partition
   4         7399424       105601762   46.8 GiB    8300  
   5       636571648       703281151   31.8 GiB    8200  
   6       105603072       636571647   253.2 GiB   8300

Comment: *DO NOT* put program output in comments; it's often too long and the forum software mangles the formatting into near-uselessness. Instead, *edit* your question and add such output there, preceding each line with four spaces. That will preserve the formatting and keep it legible. That said, it looks like your system is trying to boot GRUB without Shim first and falling back to using Shim. That could explain your failure before getting to GRUB. You could adjust the boot order with `sudo efibootmgr -o 1,2`.

Answer (score 1):

Rod's suggestion to use shimx64 instead of grubx64 is the answer. Using the efibootmgr or similar, I set the shim to be the bootloader, and now I have no more issues with secure boot, no matter which OS I install or boot from.
pgmer6809