# Linux Mint live USB works, but Ubuntu live USB starts, yet does not react to any key.

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, live-usb, livedvd

I assume some kernel parameters are different.
The computer is Clevo N850EJ
Any suggestions on how to overcome the problem?

Comment: Have you [checked the integrity of the Ubuntu iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) before creating the live USB?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after trying with Ubuntu 18.04.1, and adding the following to the boot string

```
 acpi_os_name=Linux acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=vendor
```