# Ubuntu 18.04 Installation Issues

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 18.04, hp

I've recently got a HP Envy 13 laptop, and I am attempting to set up dual of Windows and Ubuntu.

I disabled fast startup, put it onto the USB stick, and am able to boot into Grub. Each time I select either install ubuntu or try ubuntu, the ubuntu loading screen appears for a few seconds, then it reboots back into grub again. This happens over and over. I can boot back into Windows fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you [check the integrity of the downloaded iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) file before burning it to the USB stick?

Comment: @pomsky I've done that and no issues, I've also tried xubuntu to see if that made any difference and nothing, same issue.