# Cannot Install Ubuntu Because Can't Click With Mouse

Tags: system-installation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJvd82tbL1Y

As you can see from my video, I can drag the mouse but can't click anything after 10 seconds. Hope somebody can figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Did you [check the integrity of the downloaded ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) before making the bootable drive?