# BLACK SCREEN when trying to install Ubuntu Mate 19.04 over Manjaro 18

Tags: boot, grub2, mate, ubuntu-mate

I'm in my bios, then selected to boot from USB where the Ubuntu Mate 19.04 iso is. a GNU GRUB 2.02 menu appears with options:

```
Try Ubuntu Mate without installing
Try Ubuntu Mate without installing (safe graphics)
Install Ubuntu Mate
Install Ubuntu Mate (safe graphics)
```

Every option I choose, my screen goes black and does nothing. Feeling pretty helpless as there are basically no tutorials for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot boot into a live USB, it is very likely that your problem is one or more of the following:

**Wrong/Corrupted .ISO**

- Make certain that you have downloaded the correct .ISO for your hardware.  For example, older computers with `i386` architecture cannot run the .ISO file for `x64` systems.
- Before writing the .ISO to DVD or USB,  [verify the checksum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) for your ISO.

**.ISO Written Improperly to Disk**

- To Burn a DVD, use Brasero to "Burn Image" (Burn an existing CD/DVD image to disk)
- To make a bootable USB, use an automated tool like Etcher to select your .ISO file and the USB device.

**Faulty/Misconfigured Hardware**

- The USB flash drive that you are using may have bad sectors.
- The DVD you burned may have encountered an error during burning
- Your hard drive, motherboard, power supply, etc may have hardware problems, unrelated to software, that do not allow the installer to continue.
- Your motherboard BIOS may be set to only boot to UEFI or BIOS (compatibility-mode), and you selected the option that is not allowed, so you must change the settings in the motherboard firmware to allow the mode you want to boot from.